# Passing a PHP variable thru ssh in PHP script

Tags: php, ssh

I'm quite new using ssh command thru a php script.

Here my script :

```
<?
$ark =123456-78

$Sark= substr("$ark", 0, -3); //123456
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'grep $sark /var/log/transfer.log');
...
?>
```

When I put the value of $sark in clear, the ssh execution work fine but when I use the variable it's not working ( very long loading).

I also tried to declare my variable as

```
$sark= escapeshellarg('$sark');
```

I know that a php variable cannot be recognized in ssh command. I have not yet found any solution. Do you have any idea to solve this issue ?

Thank you
Rflow

Comment: When using substitution for $sark - you should be using double quotes not single round the whole string (also try and ensure use same case for consistency).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to escape it in your command
2. You where missing ;
3. It's $Sark not $sark

Result:

```
<?php
$ark =123456-78;

$Sark= substr("$ark", 0, -3); //123456
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'grep '.$Sark.' /var/log/transfer.log');
...
?>
```

Comment: Thank you , you made my day ;) It works just fine :)